# Incomplete result when calling the function find() beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl this [url](http://www.dailystormer.com/races-may-be-scientifically-identifiable-but-they-dont-actually-exist/) for research purpose, but I got an incomplete result:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
article = soup.find("div", { "class" : "entry" })
print(article)
```

It give me this result:

```
<div class="entry">
<header><strong>Racial Forensics in an Age of Race Denial</strong></header></div>
```

But when I'm looking at the code source of the page I can see a lot more:

```
<div class="entry">
<header><strong>Racial Forensics in an Age of Race Denial</strong></p>
</header>
<p>Austen Layard<br/>
<a href="http://www.theoccidentalobserver.net/2014/01/racial-forensics-in-an-age-of-race-denial/"><strong>Occidental Observer</strong></a><br/>
February 3, 2014</p>
....
</div>
```

The difference between this URL and a lot of others that I have processed is the presence of the tag `header`.

Is that tag the origin of my problem?
How can I retrieve the totality of the content of the tag `div`?

Comment: @MYGz doesn't work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
```

`html.parser` is unstable and highly unrecommended, by default, bs4 use `lxml`, let's stay with default.